# I'm not able to do cross domain ajax call for the given API

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, jsonp

I wanted to get JSON response from following API but gives me following error,
API https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?number=1902072620

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I have tried Ajax call this way,

```
  $.ajax({
     url: 'https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?number=1902072620',
     dataType: 'JSONP',
     jsonpCallback: 'callback',
     type: 'GET',
     success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
     }
   });
```

Please help me to figure out this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: "I wanted to get JSON response" — And you are getting one. You are telling jQuery to expect a JSONP response though.

Comment: @Quentin  Could you please, tell me how to get successful json response from above API with above example

Comment: Did you read my last comment at all? You are already getting a successful JSON response. The code you wrote is failing because you are telling it to expect a JSONP response.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks, but what i need to change in code.

Comment: @Quentin if I remove jsonp, it gives cross origin issue

Comment: — So your site doesn't have permission from npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov to read their data. Take it up with npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov.